# Razor Syntax Not working the way I expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

having some trouble with my razor syntax

gives a Parsor error saying that 
The foreach block is missing a closing "}" character

```
<ul>
@{var client = "null";}
@foreach (var instance in Model)
{
   if (instance.tbl_Policy.tbl_Client.txt_clientName != client)
   {
       client = instance.tbl_Policy.tbl_Client.txt_clientName;
      </ul><h1>@client</h1>   
      <ul>
   }
   <li>
    @instance.tbl_Policy.txt_policyNumber - 
    Assigned to : @instance.aspnet_Membership.aspnet_User.UserName
    @instance.ATLCheckType.Question
   <button type="button" rel="<%:instance.ATLCheckInstanceId.ToString()%>">DelFiled</button>
   <button type="button" rel="<%:instance.ATLCheckInstanceId.ToString()%>">DelLineItem</button>
   </li>  
}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Razor cannot handle imbalanced HTML tags in code blocks.

Change your `if` block to treat the imbalanced tags as plain text:

```
   if (instance.tbl_Policy.tbl_Client.txt_clientName != client)
   {
       client = instance.tbl_Policy.tbl_Client.txt_clientName;
      @:</ul><h1>@client</h1>   
      @:<ul>
   }
```

Comment: I wish you would stop suggesting `@:` as the solution for fixing up poorly written code. Though I do understand that sometimes people need the simplest answer that can unblock them :)

Comment: @MarcinD: Yes; you're right.  I actually suggested a GroupBy in a more recent answer today.

Comment: saw that and provided a similar answer with fixed up view logic in the other question :)

Answer (score 7):

The code should be refactored to correctly support balanced tags

```
@foreach (var groupedClient in Model.GroupBy(i => i.tbl_Policy.tbl_Client.txt_clientName))
{
   <ul>
   <h1>@groupedClient.Key</h1>

   foreach(var instance in groupedClient)
   {
       <li>
       @instance.tbl_Policy.txt_policyNumber - 
       Assigned to : @instance.aspnet_Membership.aspnet_User.UserName
       @instance.ATLCheckType.Question
       <button type="button" rel="@instance.ATLCheckInstanceId.ToString()">DelFiled</button>
       <button type="button" rel="@instance.ATLCheckInstanceId.ToString()">DelLineItem</button>
       </li>
   }
   </ul>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the refactor help... I have given an upvote for that.

Answer (score 2):

What's with all of the `<%: %>` stuff in there?  You need to use the `@` syntax.

```
<ul>
@{var client = "null";}
@foreach (var instance in Model)
{
   if (instance.tbl_Policy.tbl_Client.txt_clientName != client)
   {
       client = instance.tbl_Policy.tbl_Client.txt_clientName;
      </ul><h1>@client</h1>   
      <ul>
   }
   <li>
    @instance.tbl_Policy.txt_policyNumber - 
    Assigned to : @instance.aspnet_Membership.aspnet_User.UserName
    @instance.ATLCheckType.Question
   <button type="button" rel="@instance.ATLCheckInstanceId.ToString()">DelFiled</button>
   <button type="button" rel="@instance.ATLCheckInstanceId.ToString()">DelLineItem</button>
   </li>  
}
</ul>
```

Comment: Well that certainly helps (I am transferring a subset of my old ASPX view engine over)

Comment: The parser did not regonize the syntax of the code nuggets and never arrived at the closing bracket.