# How to deal with apparently mismatched HTML tags in Razor Engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Here is the case:

```
@{
    if (A)
    {
        <div>
            <span>bla</span>
      <!-- This is where it breaks! -->
    }
    else
    {
            <span>bla</span>
    }
    if(B)
    {
        </div>
    }
}
```

Since the `<div>` isn't closed inside the same condition where it's opened, Razor Engine thinks that the else statement is HTML mark-up.  What could I possibly do in situations like this to make it work properly?

Comment: Code like this can always be refactored so that the tags are balanced. While `<text>` and `@:` can be used as a quick and dirty solution it does not help with readability. Consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304261/razor-syntax-not-working-the-way-i-expected/5316225#5316225 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313969/razor-html-conditional-output/5316017#5316017

Comment: @marcind - Wow!  That's exactly and I mean EXACTLY like the case that I was dealing with!  Excellent solution, I love it!  +1

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Razor HTML Conditional Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313969/razor-html-conditional-output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is mismatched html tags. The easy way around this is to use the `@:` parser directive

```
@{
    bool A = true;
    bool B = true;

    if (A)
    {
        @:<div>
            <span>bla</span>
      <!-- This is where it breaks! -->
    }
    else
    {
            <span>bla</span>
    }
    if(B) {
        @:</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That works and I don't have to use text element.  Could you explain to me the use of @: and text element?  Or maybe point me to an article of some kind?

Comment: Simply the `text` element is to wrap non html text, say you just wanted to output a multi-line `blah blah blah` you would wrap the text element in that. The `@:` basically outputs that single line. Here's a link that explains it all: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx